# Return remaining values of an array

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

As you can see here, I return the two largest integers of my array.

```
int[] a = {a1 = (int) ((Math.random() * 10) + 1), a2 = (int) ((Math.random() * 10) + 1), a3 = (int) ((Math.random() * 10) + 1), a4 = (int) ((Math.random() * 10) + 1), a5 = (int) ((Math.random() * 10) + 1)};

public static int[] showtwolargestints(int a[]) {   // returns two largest integers of my array
int largestA = Integer.MIN_VALUE, largestB = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for(int value : a) {
 if(value > largestA) {
  largestB = largestA;
  largestA = value;
} else if (value > largestB) {
  largestB = value;
}
}
  return new int[] { largestA, largestB };  
}
```

I managed to use them in an if statement in my GUI class / JButton method.

```
int[] twoLargest = myobject.showtwolargestints(myobject.a);

public void buttonmethod() {   
try {                         
if (twoLargest[0] == 10 && twoLargest[1] == 10) {
// ...
} else if (twoLargest[0] == 10 && twoLargest[1] == 9) {
// ...
}
```

However, I now figured out, that for my programm I also have to use every single remaining integer of my array in an if statement after having found these two largest values.

I am a beginner and my attempts did not work out very well :l Could you help me out in a simple way?

PS: I neither want to sum the remaining values (I need every single one) nor want to sort them all by Bubblesort or sth. like that.

Comment: cant you use `myobject.a` for "use every single remaining integer of my array in an if statement"

Answer (score 1):

1) fast and not clean/maintainable way : instead of returning a array of two int, return a array with first the two largest int and after them (so from the index 2, add the other int values in the array).

2) cleanest way : return a instance of a class that has three fields :

- int max;
- int beforeMax;
- int[] remainings;

Then you have two ways of proceeding :

- the optimized  way : adding the values in the `remainingInts` array during your actual iteration. It requires to make some computations during the loop.
- the unoptimized way : after finding two max values, iterating the array again and adding in `remainings` array values different from  two max values.

With the clean way without optimization, your method could look like :

```
public static TwoLargestIntAndRemainingValues computeTwoLargestIntAndRemainingValues(int a[]) {

    // returns two largest integers of my array
    int largestA = Integer.MIN_VALUE, largestB = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    for (int value : a) {
        if (value > largestA) {
            largestB = largestA;
            largestA = value;

        } else if (value > largestB) {
            largestB = value;
        } 
    }

    // changes here

    // if minus three values, you have no remaining to handle
    int[] remainings= null;

    if (a.length > 2) {
        remainings= new int[a.length - 2];
        int i = 0;
        for (int value : a) {
            if (value != largestA && value != largestB) {
                remainings[i++] = value;
            }
        }
    }

    return new TwoLargestIntAndRemainingValues(largestA, largestB, remainings);
 }
```

and the data structure could be :

```
public class TwoLargestIntAndRemainingValues {

    private int max;
    private int beforeMax;
    private int[] remainings;

    public TwoLargestIntAndRemainingValues(int max, int beforeMax, int[] remainings) {
        this.max = max;
        this.beforeMax = beforeMax;
        this.remainings = remainings;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TwoLargestIntAndRemainingValues [max=" + max + ", beforeMax=" + beforeMax + ", remainings="
                + Arrays.toString(remainings) + "]";
    }

    public int getMax() {
        return max;
    }

    public int getBeforeMax() {
        return beforeMax;
    }

    public int[] getRemainings() {
        return remainings;
    }

}
```

**EDIT for how to get the values :**

```
TwoLargestIntAndRemainingValues result = myobject.computeTwoLargestIntAndRemainingValues(myobject.a);

public void buttonmethod() {   
  try {                         
    if (result.getMax() == 10 && result.getBeforeMax() == 10) {
    // ...
    } else if (result.getMax()  == 10 && result.getBeforeMax() == 9) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Okay, but how is it supposed to look like in my GUI?                                int[] leftover = myobject.computeTwoLargestIntAndRemainingValues(myobject.a);
      
      if (leftover[0] == 1) {                                                                      does not work as "twolargerstin..." cannot be converted to int[]

Comment: you should add  getters in TwoLargestIntAndRemainingValues() to get max, beforeMax and remainings fields. Then replace leftover[0]  by max  and leftover[1]  by before max. I updated code and added your example.

Comment: Allright, but my issue was about getting each value of the remaining integers, how is the if statement supposed to look like for them? I dont know how to compare int[] with int in this case

Comment: iterate on the int[] and do the the comparison in the loop.

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand that at all, I just started with programming a few months ago :(

Comment: Don't worry :) Can you explain what do you want to do with the remaining values ?

Comment: My Button method was that:                                                                     public void buttonmethod() {   
try {                         
if (twoLargest[0] == 10 && twoLargest[1] == 10) {
// ...
} else if (twoLargest[0] == 10 && twoLargest[1] == 9) {
// ...
}

Comment: No I also want another try catch with                                                             if("firstremainingsvalue" == 2) {                                                                                 // just do some stuff   // and else ifs with "firstremaingsvalue" == 2,3,4 etc and also if statements with "SECONDremaingvalue" == 0 etc. I just do not understand how to put them into an if statement

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
//Assuming a is an array of 5 integers and you already know the 2 largest

int[] remaining = new int[3];
int j = 0;
for(int i : a){
    if(i != twoLargest[0] && i != twoLargest[1]){
        remaining[j] = i;
        j++;
    }
}
```